# O que '%02x' faz exatamente?

Tags: c, formatação, openssl, hexadecimal

Estava vendo alguns [exemplos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262386/generate-sha256-with-openssl-and-c) de funções *hash* da OpenSSL e acabei me deparando com o [especificador de formato](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programar_em_C/Entrada_e_sa%C3%ADda_simples#Especifica%C3%A7%C3%B5es_de_formato) `%02x`. Eu não sei muito bem a sua finalidade nós códigos que vi. Até entendo que o `%02x` serve para preencher o campo com zeros e o 2 é numero de zeros que vai ter nesse preenchimento (eu acho que isso).

Bom, aqui vai um código elaborado por mim onde tive que usar (não sei por que tive que usar) o `%02x`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

void get_string(char *string, size_t max_input_size){

    fgets(string, max_input_size, stdin);

    unsigned int len=strlen(string);

    string[len-1]='\0';
}

int main(void){

    char string[50];
    unsigned char digest[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    printf("Write >");
    get_string(string, 50);

    SHA256((unsigned char*)string, strlen(string), digest);

    char stringMD[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH*2+1];

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++){

        sprintf(&stringMD[i*2], "%02x", (unsigned int)digest[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\nDigest: %s\n\n", stringMD);

    return 0;
}
```

Execução (com o `%02x`):

```
Write >FN P90

Digest: 45603ce52cd32a33e3e60c219d0c18e6bd32af24ac39aa000d84e763d23c3031
```

Execução (com apenas o `%x`):

```
Write >FN P90

Digest: 45603ce52cd32a33e3e6c
```

Contudo, qual a finalidade do `%02x`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) apresenta o número inteiro como hexadecimal garantindo que tenha sempre 2 dígitos, sendo o 0 usado à esquerda se tiver apenas 1 ou 0 dígitos. Geralmente é a única forma de gerar hexadecimal corretamente, especialmente em casos onde ele é só parte de um número maior.

Answer (score 0):

Você tem uma "string" chamada `stringMD`, que pode ter lixo, no início do programa.

Se você não preencher *todas* as suas posições com algo, em certa região dela pode haver caracteres `\0`.

Como você está a preenchendo de dois em dois (vide abaixo),

```
sprintf(/* destaque ao i*2 >>>>*/ &stringMD[i*2], "%02x", ...
```

se você esquecer do `02` do formato, o preenchimento poderá ser parcial.